# how to create temp file without random number

Tags: java

I need to send pdf file  as attachment with mail. This is scheduler job which run every 2 hour.Directly it's not taking giving File Not Found Exception so i thought i put in temp directory and send from there. This job is run on JBoss Server.

```
File temp = null;
String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "SupplierGuide";try
{
    temp = File.createTempFile(tDir, ".pdf");
    final InputStream inputStream = SendNotificationToContacts.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(result.getProperty("supplier.guide"));

    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(temp));
}catch(
Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I want file name  "SupplierGuide.pdf".

Comment: Where are you getting a random number?

Comment: Why dont you just take the file name you want? (`temp = new File("whatever name you want");`) Btw. Interesting code formatting approach.

Comment: Actually first problem is...I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException on server while debug locally it's working fine. I am having one PDF file which is part of the jar itself. This PDF will be send in the mail.

This jar will run on server by kjb job.

Comment: To resolve first problem, i create temp file. now name having random number.

Comment: you should ask yourself why you need to create a file to begin with? why not write directly to the `InputStream` of the email attachment and skip the disk I/O completely

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on Apache Tomcat 7.0.65 web server from a servlet. This routine also uses Java 7 and Apache Commons IO Utils (`commons-io-1.3.2.jar`).

```
private void createUserGuideInTempFolder()
        throws IOException {
    String inputFileName = "N:\\TestData\\user-guide.pdf";
    String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(inputFileName);
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputFileName);
    Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(baseName, extension);
    Path inputFilePath = Paths.get(inputFileName);

    InputStream inStream = Files.newInputStream(inputFilePath);
    byte [] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
    tempFilePath = Files.write(tempFilePath, fileBytes);
    System.out.println(inputFilePath);
    // Prints input file: N:\TestData\user-guide.pdf
    System.out.println(tempFilePath);
    // Prints temp file: N:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\temp\user-guide3642635958536288074pdf

    Path newTempFilePath = Paths.get(tempFilePath.getParent().toString(),
                    inputFilePath.getFileName().toString());    
    newTempFilePath = Files.move(tempFilePath, newTempFilePath);
    System.out.println(newTempFilePath);
    // Prints result file in temp: N:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\temp\user-guide.pdf
}
```